# How to create an account with a specific private key?

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

I want to give an account name to a specific private key and register it to Near blockchain, how to do it?

Comment: Please share your attempt: some research or code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [near-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/near-shell) by providing `--publicKey` option.

```
near create_account account_name --publicKey specific_public_key_in_base58  --masterAccount account_used_to_create
```